# Rectangular UISearchBar on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uisearchbar

I'm trying to make a `UISearchBar` rectangular instead of rounded, but all the solutions I found so far (mostly iterating through subviews) seem broken on iOS 7.

I did some research myself and as it turns out, it only has a `UIView` subview, which has additional subviews, a `UISearchBarBackground` and a `UISearchBarTextField` (both of them are private classes).
I tried

```
if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

and

```
if ([view conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
    @try {

        [(UITextField *)view setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        // ignore exception
    }
}
```

where `view` is the subview of that one `UIView` subview but none of them seems to work.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem partially was that I set the UISearchBar's Search Style (in IB) to minimal. If you set it to Prominent, the first piece of code works. (Actually, it's still rounded so not the perfect solution. If anybody has a better idea please share it.)

Comment: You might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @Marco See my edit to that comment, it's not the best solution but if no one comes up with a better one for a while, I'll post it.

Comment: Have you tried UISearchBar appearance methods, such as `setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:forState:`

Comment: @Rickye I misunderstood, thought you had solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... (I know it is also using subview but it is working in ios7)

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 49)];
[self.view addSubview:searchBar];
[self checkSubViewsOfView:searchBar WithTabIndex:@""];
```

and Add this method

```
-(void)checkSubViewsOfView:(UIView *)view WithTabIndex:(NSString *)strTab
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField")])
    {
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        return;
    }

    for (UIView *vvv in view.subviews)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@%@",strTab,[vvv description]);

        if (vvv.subviews > 0)
        {
            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"____%@",strTab];
            [self checkSubViewsOfView:vvv WithTabIndex:str];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good one, thanks! Closely what I ended up with. The problem with this is it kills the resizing of the UISearchBar and therefore the Cancel button never appears next to it.

Comment: @Rickye if you use this approach. it is bad. because it not come from public doc. so use Thorsten said approach is best

Answer (score 1):

you can set the searchfield-background like this:

```
[self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchbar_stretch-0-10-0-10"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and the searchbar-background like this:

```
[self.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"categories_navbar"]];
```